# How facebook API count a particular URL's total shares

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer, facebook-share

I have a question that needs your help. While we can get Facebook's share count of a particular URL via their API, I'm interested in how do they count them? I ask this because following two cases we meet:

Example One, we post one URL on the company's Facebook page as a status. Then 99 fans share this status on their timelines. So how many shares this URL get, 99,1 or 100(99+1)?

Example Two, we post an article on our site, then 99 people read it and all of them clicked share button on the page to share this article on their timelines. So how many shares this URL get, 99?

Thanks very much!

Comment: As for example one: The external URL doesn’t get any further shares/likes (besides your original one) – your post on your page does. Those are two different objects.

Comment: So, in the example one, the URL only get 1 share, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes. Everything else are shares/likes for the post on your page, not the external URL.

Comment: Then it is clear that the URL in the sample two should get 99 shares, right?